# Flutter. Text inside the Text() doesnt get updated

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of widgets and when i try to update Text inside of them, it just doesnt get updated for some reason. even when i add a new widget, rebuild and see this widget in Row (so it means screen got rebuilded) i cant see updated text. is it possible to update it, or is it static?

```
class NoteInfo {
  String _title = ""; // private backing variable

  String get Title => _title;
  set Title(String value) => _title = value;

  String _note = ""; // private backing variable

  String get Note => _note;
  set Note(String value) => _note = value;

  Icon icon = Icon(Icons.label);
  //DateTime date = DateTime(year);

  //List<Widget> active_notes = <Widget>[];

  String _shortNote = ""; // private backing variable

  String get shortNote => _shortNote;
  set shortNote(String value) => _shortNote = value;

  String _shortTitle = ""; // private backing variable

  String get shortTitle => _shortTitle;
  set shortTitle(String value) => _shortTitle = value;
}

List<NoteInfo> note_infos = [];
List<String> Titles = [];

lass HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
Widget W1(BuildContext context) {
    final key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toString());
    int index = -1;
    int ind = Titles.length - 1;
    Titles[ind] = "title" + ind.toString();
    return TextButton(
      key: key,
      onPressed: () async {
        await Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          index = active_notes.indexWhere((e) => e.key == key);
          Titles[index] = "title" + index.toString();
          return noteScreenState.note_page(
              context, index); //calling the editing menu
        }));
        Titles[ind] = "Rebuilded! " +
            index
                .toString(); //i tried to switch it to Titles[0] = "Rebuilded! " + index.toString(); and text didnt changed anyway
        setState(() {
          print("setstate"); //printed
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.label,
              color: Colors.white,
            ), ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

thanks for the help in advance.

edited: i think it not rebuilds the widdget

Answer (score 0):

First off you are not setting Text() anywhere in this code, but the issue is you need to reassign the title in the SetState. Changed the W1 widget below.

```
class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

@override    
Widget W1(BuildContext context) {
    final key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toString());
    int index = -1;
    int ind = Titles.length - 1;
    Titles[ind] = "title" + ind.toString();
    return TextButton(
      key: key,
      onPressed: () async {
        await Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          index = active_notes.indexWhere((e) => e.key == key);
          Titles[index] = "title" + index.toString();
          return noteScreenState.note_page(
              context, index); //calling the editing menu
        }));
        setState(() {
            Titles[ind] = "Rebuilded! ${index.toString()}" 
          print("setstate"); 
        },);
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.label,
              color: Colors.white,
            ), ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Text still not changes

Comment: where are you displaying the text?

Comment: in this:

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
//,,,
  Widget home_page(BuildContext context) {
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: active_notes), //active_notes is the list with Widgets
       ),    );
} 

}